# CORS in Azure function on Raspberry pi 3B

Tags: c#, docker, azure-functions, raspberry-pi3

I have Azure functions V2 running on my raspberry pi 3 in a docker container. 
I can access the functions via the ip-address of the pi in the network.
My problem is that I can't access it from my website because of CORS.

If my Functions where running in the cloud, I could easily add CORS.
Does anyone know how I could fix this on the raspberry pi? 
Update docker file or change files?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is basically just sending the appropriate headers in your response.

On Azure, this is taken care of by the platform itself but since you will be running/accessing the functions runtime directly from a container, you can just set them on the response object.

For example, if you are using NodeJS/JavaScript for your functions, set the headers using `context.res`

```
context.res = {
  status: 200,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Or the origins you want to allow requests from
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: {
    just: 'some data'
  }
};
```